# Linear constraint in convex optimization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Is it true that the solution to a linearly constrained convex minimization problem can only be placed on the boundary of the constraint set, for any nonlinear convex objective, e.g.

$$ \min_x f(x)$$ s.t. $$Ax \le b$$

when $f$ is convex?

If yes, why?

Update: I guess the answer is no. 
$\min (x-2)^2$ s.t. 
$x \le 100$

But then why adding a $L_1$ norm to convex objectives leads to exact sparsity?

By exact sparsity I mean all elements of the solution vector are either zero or one.(As opposed to $L_2$ norm regularization that only shrinks value of solution.) The reason I heard was that solution is guaranteed to happen on vertices of $L_1$ ball and on the vertices all elements are either zero or one.

Comment: What do you mean by "exact sparsity"? The addition of the $L_1$ norm does *not* guarantee the sparsest solution in general; only under specific conditions for specific models.

Comment: By exact sparsity I mean all elements of the solution vector are either zero or one.(As apposed to L2 norm regularization that only shrinks value of solution.) The reason I heard was that solution is guaranteed to happen on edges of $L_1$ ball and on the edges all elements are either zero or one.

Comment: Again, that is simply not true in general. It can sometimes be guaranteed under certain circumstances (e.g., compressed sensing models where the RIP property is satisfied), but there is no universal result. The use of the $L_1$ regularization *tends* to promote sparsity, and there are good theoretical reasons why it does, but it does guarantee it.

Comment: Furthermore, it is not the case that on the edges of the $L_1$ ball the elements are zero or one. This is only true for the vertices. For instance, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $x=(1/n,1/n,...,1/n)$ is on the edge of the $L_1$ ball.

Comment: Right I meant to say vertices.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this is not correct, you are confused. Convex function might have an optimum without any constraints like you showed yourself. I am not sure I understood your last question regarding $L_1$ norm but coming back to the original problem actuall the opposite is true - a linear (or concave) function on convex sets  always has an optimum on the boundary.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Any pointer to a proof of this opposite statement?

Comment: You can search on internet "convex mathematical programming problem, convex optimization, linear programming", it is a quite basic fact.A linear or concave function cannot have minimum without constraints. So if it has it should be on the boundary. So if the constraint set is compact and concave - a solution exists.  Uniqueness requires stronger conditions.